# Applying effects to output instead of bitmaps?

Tags: c++, effects, direct2d

Let's say I have a gaussian blur effect `ID2D1Effect *blur;` and I want to apply a bitmap to the effect to get a blured image. I can pass the bitmap to the effect using `blur->SetInput(0, bitmap);` and get the output with `blur->Get()`. Now I don't want to blur an image stored on disk, I want to blur the output that I created between `renderTarget->BeginDraw()` and `renderTarget->EndDraw()`. My first idea was to get a bitmap of the output, but I could find neither a function for retrieving the already rendered output nor find a way to apply an effect to the renderTarget instead of a loaded bitmap.

Little example:

```
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *brush;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *renderTarget; // Instantiated somewhere else in code

renderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(0.0f, 0.6f, 1.0f), &bush);

renderTarget->BeginDraw();
renderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
renderTarget->FillRectangle(D2D1::RectF(50.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f), brush);
// Apply gaussian blur?
renderTarget->EndDraw();

brush->Release();
// renderTarget gets released somewhere else
```

How can I blur the rectangle in this example?

---

**EDIT** (Thanks to *enhzflep*):

I can obtain the already rendered output as a bitmap with following snippet:

```
ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget *bitmapRenderTarget;
hwndRenderTarget->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(&bitmapRenderTarget);

ID2D1Bitmap *bitmap;
bitmapRenderTarget->GetBitmap(&bitmap);
```

In my code I already tested it by obtaining a bitmap, drawing on it and finally draw this bitmap onto the `hwndRenderTarget` and it worked. Before drawing the bitmap back to the `hwndRenderTarget` I want to apply an effect to it (e.g. gaussian blur). But this leads to the next problem (I don't know if I should open a new topic, so I post it here): An `ID2D1Effect` interface can only be instantiated from an instance of `ID2D1DeviceContext` which is only available for Windows 8. I cannot imagine that Microsoft restricts `ID2D1Effect` to Windows 8, so there have to be another way. **Does anyone know another way of instatiating an** `ID2D1Effect` **interface?**

---

**EDIT 2**:

I also posted this question on MSDN and finally got an [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33e35758-0a15-4c90-bbb5-55c566f019ed/direct2d-using-effects-on-windows-7?forum=vclanguage#33e35758-0a15-4c90-bbb5-55c566f019ed). I had to install the [Platform Update for Win7 SP1 (KB2670838)](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838/de-de?ppud=4&wa=wsignin1.0) and the [Win8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) (also works on Win7) in order to use Win8 headers on Win7.

(Final solution below as answer)

Comment: I suspect that the idea is to render the scene to a bitmap, filter that then show the result.

Comment: So instead using a HwndRenderTarget for rendering, I should use BitmapRenderTarget?

Comment: Sounds like a likely candidate. (I dont know DX at all)

Comment: Even if you don't know DX, you had an idea that helped me :) Now I only have to apply the effect to the bitmap. I didn't even get an answer from MSDN yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my final solution. It's simpler than I though it's gonna be:

```
// Obtain already initialized ID2D1HwndRenderTarget
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *hwndRenderTarget = Game::GetInstance()->gfx->hwndRenderTarget;

// COMs
ID2D1Bitmap *bitmap;
ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget *bitmapRenderTarget;
ID2D1DeviceContext *deviceContext;
ID2D1Effect *gaussianBlur;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *solidColorBrush;

// Create bitmapRenderTarget
hwndRenderTarget->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(&bitmapRenderTarget);

// Create solidColorBrush
bitmapRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(0.0f, 0.6f, 1.0f), &solidColorBrush);

// Draw onto bitmapRenderTarget
bitmapRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
bitmapRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
bitmapRenderTarget->FillEllipse(D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(400.0f, 300.0f), 100.0f, 100.0f), solidColorBrush);
bitmapRenderTarget->EndDraw();

// Obtain hwndRenderTarget's deviceContext
hwndRenderTarget->QueryInterface(&deviceContext);

// Create and apply gaussian blur
deviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1GaussianBlur, &gaussianBlur);

bitmapRenderTarget->GetBitmap(&bitmap);
gaussianBlur->SetInput(0, bitmap);
gaussianBlur->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_BORDER_MODE, D2D1_BORDER_MODE_SOFT);
gaussianBlur->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION, 5.0f);

// Draw resulting bitmap
deviceContext->DrawImage(
    gaussianBlur,
    D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR);

// Release
bitmap->Release();
bitmapRenderTarget->Release();
deviceContext->Release();
gaussianBlur->Release();
solidColorBrush->Release();
```

Comment: @MikeVersteeg I know, but I had to wait 24 hours to be able to mark this answer.